# Reading and reducing a .kmz

Tags: r, geospatial, tidyverse, rgdal

I'm brand new to using R geospatially.

Working .kmz: https://www.cnrfc.noaa.gov/ - from the second drop down right below the map pane titled 'Download Overlay Files', I've downloaded and I'm using the "Drainage Basins" kml that should download as "basins.kml"

```
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
```

From looking at the .kml in a text editor, it looks like the KML layer name is 
"cnrfc_09122018_basins_thin", so reading it in with:

```
cnrfc_basins <- readOGR("basins.kml", "cnrfc_09122018_basins_thin")
```

gives me a "Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame".

To be able to plot, it looks like I need to "fortify it" (?), and make a more ordinary `data.frame`, so from some other posts I've come across:

```
cnrfc_basins_fortify <- merge(broom::tidy(cnrfc_basins), 
                        as.data.frame(cnrfc_basins), by.x="id", by.y=0)
```

plotting with this:

```
ggplot() + geom_path(data = cnrfc_basins_fortify, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group))  +
           coord_quickmap()
```

gives me the data I'm expecting:

[image]

But, for these around one hundred polygons or so, I have hundreds of thousands of data.frame rows. How do I reduce these, so I have just one row for each polygon?(Each polygon, which is representative of a particular basin, has a unique five digit ID already, in the 'Name' column). Having fewer rows seems it will make working with the file easier and quicken joins, when I will join data to these unique polygons.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want a data.frame? Why not just plot cnrfc_basins directly? Try your plot statement with `cnrfc_basins` instead of `cnrfc_basins_fortify`

Comment: I see, that worked. If I had another data.frame of observations for each of the polygons, would regular joining methods work? Thanks.

Comment: If you also get the other set of observations using `st_read`, you should be able to combine the two using `st_union`.

Comment: Fantastic - great to know. The observations originate from a .csv.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to is directly extract the `@data` contained in the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame:

`poly = cnrfc_basins@data`

That should give you a 339-row data.frame with the unique identifiers you need (without the geometric metadata)

```
> head(poly)
   Name
0 EFBC1
1 CSKC1
2 CMIC1
3 FMDC1
4 NMFC1
5 NFDC1
```